# Merging overlapping datasets

Tags: javascript, java, json, merge, dataset

Given multiple datasets that may/may not overlap on one or more columns, I am looking to dynamically merge the datasets together.

Is there a library or code snippet that will merge datasets in this manner? How about just doing it using a single column as a key?

EXAMPLE: Merging two datasets, using multiple columns as keys (BookTitle, Author)

**Input, Dataset 1**

```
BookTitle, Author, Publisher
title1, author1, publisher1
title2, author2, publisher2
title3, author3, publisher3
```

**Input, Dataset 2**

```
BookTitle, Author, NumPages
title4, author4, numPages4
title7, author7, numPages7
title5, author5, numPages5
title3, author33, numPages3
title2, author2, numPages2
```

**Output, Munged Dataset**

```
BookTitle, Author, Publisher, NumPages
title1, author1, publisher1, _null_
title2, author2, publisher2, numPages2
title3, author3, publisher3, _null_
title4, author4, _null_, numPages4
title5, author5, _null_, numPages5
title7, author7, _null_, numPages7
title3, author33, _null_, numPages3
```

I have done some research and nothing immediately useful came up (mostly about one-time merges of JSON objects in the same structure (ie, appending data, as opposed to merging distinct datasets)).

I am looking for a Java/JavaScript, using JSON/XML/CSV data (in order of preference) but will accept other languages assuming that those algorithms can be ported over.

I will also consider accepting examples where this is being done on a single column only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't really look for a library for something so simple. Instead try building a solution yourself.

You could first `JSON.parse()` any strings to convert them into objects. Then, you could pass both these objects into a function that looks something like this.

```
function mergeSets(first, second) {
    var result = first;
    second.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        var resultIndex = contains(result, item);
        if (resultIndex === -1) {
            result.push(item);
        } else {
            result[resultIndex].numPages = item.numPages;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Notice that `mergeSets()` calls `contains()` which is essentially as follows.

```
function contains(set, object) {
    var solution = -1;
    set.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        if (item.bookTitle == object.bookTitle && item.author == object.author) {
            solution = index;
        }
    });
    return solution;
}
```

It really isn't too hard as you can see. Sorry for some of the variable names. This was written in a hurry. Also, you mention in your example of the resulting set that you would like the fields that aren't available to be displayed as `null` which is not appropriate since `null` usually indicates an empty reference. Instead, I have ignored them. Accessing those fields on objects in the array that don't have them would result in `undefined` which makes perfect sense.

Also, the following are the limitations of the code in the fiddle. You may edit it to ease out these limitations and make it more robust.

1. It is tied to the data format you have mentioned in your question. To make it work for arbitrary sets, you can check for the existence of a property using `Object.hasOwnProperty()` in a for-in loop and add the necessary ones resulting in a merge.
2. It doesn't handle duplicates within sets in anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/x5Q5g/

**Edit:** Oh! And by the way, the code is JavaScript and the data format could be JSON provided you use `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`.

**Edit:** The following updates negate the first limitation mentioned above. Notice that you need to pass in the key to compare on the basis of, explicitly.

```
function contains(set, object, key) {
    var solution = -1;
    set.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        if (item[key] === object[key]) {
            solution = index;
        }
    });
    return solution;
}

function mergeSets(first, second, key) {
    var result = first;
    second.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        var resultIndex = contains(result, item, key);
        if (resultIndex === -1) {
            result.push(item);
        } else {
            result[resultIndex].numPages = item.numPages;
            for (var property in item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    if (!result[resultIndex].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        result[resultIndex].property = item.property;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var solution = mergeSets(firstSet, secondSet, "bookTitle");
console.log(solution);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6HqL/

**One final update:** Here is how you can make it accept any number of keys. I had forgotten that you require multiple key support. Sorry!

You need to change the following.

```
function contains(set, object, keys) {
    var solution = -1;
    set.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        var selfItem = item;
        var allKeys = keys.every(function (item, index, array) {
            if (selfItem[item] === object[item]) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        if (allKeys) {
            solution = index;
        }
    });
    return solution;
}

function mergeSets(first, second) {
    var result = first;
    var keys = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    second.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
        var resultIndex = contains(result, item, keys);
        if (resultIndex === -1) {
            result.push(item);
        } else {
            for (var property in item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    if (!result[resultIndex].hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        var hello = result[resultIndex];
                        hello[property] = item[property];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var solution = mergeSets(firstSet, secondSet, "bookTitle", "author");
console.log(solution);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6HqL/3/

This last fiddle and code above it is complete. Without any references! And is generic. Would work with any number of keys as arguments.

Comment: This looks like an interesting starting point, thank you. The part not solved by this solution is that the structure of the datasets, and the columns on which these datasets will be merged, is dynamic (ie, unknown until runtime / provided by the user). It may simply be a case of pulling these out to parameters..?

Comment: Too late to edit my comment, but the 'library' comment is intended to be a hint that I'm looking for something generic, as opposed to it being coded to specific datasets. I'll look at editing the question to be clearer :).

Comment: Let me edit my solution and make it generic for you. Hold on.

Comment: I've upvoted you, but as it is not complete I'm hesitating to mark as the correct answer (eg, still has references to .numPages). I'll have a play to make it more generic still. Assuming there's not a more complete answer posted in the meanwhile, I'm happy to mark this as correct once I'm done (and share the fiddle back) as you will have helped significantly :)

Comment: Oops. I forgot to remove that line. It works without it! You don't need any reference to numPages. Check the last fiddle.

Comment: Oh cool, cheers! Accepted as you answer the question I've asked! :) You deserve more than just the one upvote/acceptance rep for being responsive and helpful!

Comment: Ah. Don't worry about it. You're always welcome. This is what this website is all about.